# neovim auto-indentation nuances

Tags: vim, neovim

I've just switched from vim to neovim. The following vim config settings get the behaviour I want from indentation:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

The relevant part here is the autoindent:

```
set autoindent
```

On each newline, this causes vim to match the indentation of the previous line:

```
def demo_autoindent():
    a = 'This line was manually indented'
····
```

The declaration of `a` was manually indented one step, but the second line was auto-indented to the same level. Here **I have represented the auto-indent with a series of `·` characters.**

Neovim matches this behaviour. However, Neovim tries to be a bit clever with blocks, or in this case declaring dictionaries in python:

```
def example_neovim():
    b = {
············
```

Note that Neovim has *not* auto-indented this line. If it had, it would have the same 4-space indent as the declaration of `b`. Instead, Neovim has added an extra **two** indents, bringing the total to 12-spaces.

Clearly what it intends to do is add one further indent:

```
def example_neovim_intention():
    c = {
········
```

**How do I configure Neovim to either:**

1. Match the behaviour of vim, just auto-indent to the same level.
2. Add a single (rather than a double) extra indent when declaring e.g. a dict.

Comment: This is driving me a bit nuts, too. I was sure to drop into a config-free environment to test and I'm coming up against the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing exactly the same issue, I used VIM for quite a long time and recently I switch to NeoVim.

Auto indention on  for every other languages except "python" works well. I found this document quite useful: https://neovim.io/doc/user/indent.html#ft-python-indent .

```
:h ft-python-indent
```

NeoVim will check this variable `g:python_indent`, if it is not defined a default one will be created, and it would be something like this (NeoVim 0.8.2):

```
{
  'disable_parentheses_indenting': v:false,
  'closed_paren_align_last_line': v:true,
  'searchpair_timeout': 150,
  'continue': 'shiftwidth() * 2',
  'open_paren': 'shiftwidth() * 2',
  'nested_paren': 'shiftwidth()'
}
```

Change these properties `continue`,`open_paren` and `closed_paren_align_last_line` as follows.

```
{
  'disable_parentheses_indenting': v:false,
  'closed_paren_align_last_line': v:false,
  'searchpair_timeout': 150,
  'continue': 'shiftwidth()',
  'open_paren': 'shiftwidth()',
  'nested_paren': 'shiftwidth()'
}
```

### Another Approach (Recommended)

This can fix the weird indention issue easier.

Setup [nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) and turn on tree-sitter's indention feature.

```lua
require('nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter').setup {
  ...
  indent = { enable = true },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well done - that's much better than my solution.

Comment: nvim-treesitter has bugs for python indent.

Comment: Indent wasn't working for me, no matter what I tried. After I commented indent in treesitter configuration, it started working.

Comment: nvim-treesitter indent is still buggy as hell. no any indentation is less annoying than one provided by it.